# Javascript: How to check the existence of a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to check the whether an external url like http://www.example.com exists or not using javascript or ajax.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You realize that you're likely being blocked by the same origin policy and for security reasons, you cannot just check if page is found? ("200 OK")

Comment: You can make a server-side (PHP, maybe) page that checks for you, and have JavaScript use AJAX to talk to that page.

Answer (score 3):

You can load it into a hidden iframe and see if you get content. You **can't** use "ajax" (e.g., an [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) call) for it, because you'll run into [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions.